# Laravel Multiple Join Issues

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am having an issue with Laravel table joining. When the following code is running its showing the result :

```
$result = DB::table('users')
        ->join('role_user', 'users.id', '=', 'role_user.user_id')
        ->where('role_user.role_id', $roleId)        
        ->join('roles', 'role_user.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
        ->select('users.*','role_user.role_id','roles.display_name','roles.description')           
        ->get();
```

But when I am breaking the code into following :

```
$result = DB::table('users'); 
        $result->join('role_user', function ($join) {
            $join->on('role_user.role_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->where('role_user.role_id', $roleId);          

        });
        $result->join('roles', function ($join){
             $join->on('role_user.role_id', '=', 'roles.id');
        });
        $result->select('users.*','role_user.role_id','roles.display_name','roles.description');
        $result->get();
```

Seems that the 'roles' table having the join with 'user' table, but it need to be joined with 'role_user' table as it is on first Query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what you exactly want? the question is ambiguous

Comment: Have you not thought about using a relation to do this? If your using a pivot table for the roles_users a user would have belongsToMany roles and the same for roles, then you can do users::with('roles) or roles::with('users')

Comment: @Sletheren I am having a problem with joining the second table and third table with the relation. Third table is trying to join with the first one.

Comment: @rchatburn that can be done in a usual way, which I am doing in first query. But the style of second I need the same.

Comment: Im a little confused as to what you need as it just looks like your getting all users with x role and if your only wanting the select fields you can use pluck() in your relation

Comment: @rchatburn I need the second query run and return the same as first one.

Comment: why you don't use the first one?

Comment: @nasimjahednia obviously there is some need.

Comment: please write hear your tables name and their columns; i think i found th problem

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access the variable $roleId within the closure/ anonymous function. Therefore, you need to pass this variable to the closure. This should lead to the same result.

```
$result = DB::table('users')
    ->join('role_user', function ($join) use ($roleId) {
        $join->on('role_user.role_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->where('role_user.role_id', $roleId)
    })
    ->join('roles', function ($join){
         $join->on('role_user.role_id', '=', 'roles.id');
    })
    ->select('users.*','role_user.role_id','roles.display_name','roles.description')       
    ->get();
```

Comment: I think you have given the same as first one. I need the format of second one.

Comment: @Tristup updated the query according to your needs. Should be working correctly, tested it locally.

Comment: But @fab I need it to be broken into different like my second query. Where the roles table is not connecting to role_users where the relationship is. It building the relation with the users table. Please try to get the same format as second one.

Comment: It has exactly the same format as your second one. Please describe with a simple example what you are trying to achieve. Have you tried to use Laravel's the hasManyThrough() relationship type?